# Try to install gtk on mac missing dependencies

Tags: macos, haskell, gcc, gtk2hs

I tried to install the gtk haskell on my mac. I used [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Mac) site to install it. However I failed at the last step with the command: `sudo cabal install --with-gcc=gcc-4.8 gtk`

the terminal answer is:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: gtk (user goal)
rejecting: gtk-0.14.5, gtk-0.14.4, gtk-0.14.3, gtk-0.14.2, gtk-0.13.9,
gtk-0.13.8.1, gtk-0.13.8, gtk-0.13.7, gtk-0.13.6, gtk-0.13.4, gtk-0.13.3,
gtk-0.13.2, gtk-0.13.1, gtk-0.13.0.3, gtk-0.13.0.2, gtk-0.13.0.1,
gtk-0.13.0.0, gtk-0.12.5.7, gtk-0.12.5.6, gtk-0.12.5.5, gtk-0.12.5.4,
gtk-0.12.5.3, gtk-0.12.5.2, gtk-0.12.5.1, gtk-0.12.5.0, gtk-0.12.4,
gtk-0.12.3.1, gtk-0.12.3, gtk-0.12.2, gtk-0.12.1, gtk-0.12.0, gtk-0.11.2,
gtk-0.11.1, gtk-0.11.0 (conflict: requires pkg-config package gtk+-2.0-any,
not found in the pkg-config database)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Cabal should be up-to-date.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** After doing ErikR recipe, it started to install with the command `cabal install gtk`. This is the error message, I got:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring glib-0.13.4.0...
Building glib-0.13.4.0...
Installed glib-0.13.4.0
Downloading gio-0.13.3.0...
Downloading pango-0.13.3.0...
Configuring gio-0.13.3.0...
Configuring pango-0.13.3.0...
Building gio-0.13.3.0...
Building pango-0.13.3.0...
Installed pango-0.13.3.0
Installed gio-0.13.3.0
Downloading gtk-0.14.5...
Configuring gtk-0.14.5...
Building gtk-0.14.5...
Failed to install gtk-0.14.5
Build log ( /Users/Max/.cabal/logs/gtk-0.14.5.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/kr/2w9n7xxd6816d0rmgb05cfm00000gn/T/cabal-tmp-31721/gtk-0.14.5'
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/kr/2w9n7xxd6816d0rmgb05cfm00000gn/T/cabal-tmp-31721/gtk-0.14.5/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/kr/2w9n7xxd6816d0rmgb05cfm00000gn/T/cabal-tmp-31721/gtk-0.14.5/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/kr/2w9n7xxd6816d0rmgb05cfm00000gn/T/cabal-tmp-31721/gtk-0.14.5/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring gtk-0.14.5...
Building gtk-0.14.5...
Preprocessing library gtk-0.14.5...
[  1 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.ModelView.Sequence ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/ModelView/Sequence.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/ModelView/Sequence.o )
[  2 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Enums ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/Enums.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/Enums.o )
[  3 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.Enums ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Enums.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Enums.o )
[  4 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.Threading ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Threading.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Threading.o )
[  5 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Signals ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Signals.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Signals.o )
[  6 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Types.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Types.o )
[  7 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.DNDTypes ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/DNDTypes.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/DNDTypes.o )
[  8 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.ContainerChildProperties ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/ContainerChildProperties.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/ContainerChildProperties.o )
[  9 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Embedding.Types ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Types.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Types.o )
[ 10 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Embedding.Embedding ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Embedding.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Embedding.o )
[ 11 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.ModelView.Types ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/ModelView/Types.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/ModelView/Types.o )
[ 12 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.PixbufData ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/PixbufData.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/PixbufData.o )
[ 13 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.PixbufAnimation ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/PixbufAnimation.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/PixbufAnimation.o )
[ 14 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Builder ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Builder.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Builder.o )
[ 15 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Separator ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Separator.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Separator.o )
[ 16 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Scrollbar ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Scrollbar.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Scrollbar.o )
[ 17 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Scale ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Scale.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Scale.o )
[ 18 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Object ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Object.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Object.o )
[ 19 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Paned ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Paned.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Paned.o )
[ 20 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.Structs ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Structs.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Structs.o )
[ 21 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Range ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Range.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Range.o )
[ 22 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Embedding.Plug ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.o )

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:120:6:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Ptr ()’
                with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    In the first argument of ‘gtk_plug_new’, namely
      ‘(fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘gtk_plug_new
         (fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:137:6:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Ptr ()’
                with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    In the second argument of ‘\ (Display arg1) arg2
                                 -> withForeignPtr arg1
                                    $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_new_for_display argPtr1 arg2’, namely
      ‘(fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘(\ (Display arg1) arg2
          -> withForeignPtr arg1
             $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_new_for_display argPtr1 arg2)
         display
         (fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:151:3:
    Couldn't match type ‘Ptr ()’ with ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    Expected type: IO (Maybe DrawWindow)
      Actual type: IO (Ptr ())
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘(\ (Plug arg1)
          -> withForeignPtr arg1 $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_get_id argPtr1)
         (toPlug self)’
    In the expression:
      liftM toNativeWindowId
      $ (\ (Plug arg1)
           -> withForeignPtr arg1 $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_get_id argPtr1)
          (toPlug self)
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/kr/2w9n7xxd6816d0rmgb05cfm00000gn/T/cabal-tmp-31721/gtk-0.14.5'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
gtk-0.14.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: What versions of cabal/ghc are you using

Comment: Which of the recipes to install gtk on that page did you follow - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6? Were you able to run `gtk-demo`? And what version of OS X are you running?

Comment: cabal version 1.24.0.0 and ghc version 7.10.3, i tried recipe 2 . and os x version 10.11.6. yes, i was able to start the demo

Comment: Now that pkg-config is finding gtk+-2.0, now what happens when you try `cabal install gtk`?

Comment: There is something amiss with your set of libraries. I would try using `stack` to build and use gtk.  If that doesn't work I would create a new issue here: https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues

Comment: Link to stack: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/

Comment: btw - what version of the gtk libraries fo you have installed? I was able to build with cabal and I have version 2.24.25 installed in /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.25.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem today and I managed to install gtk using the have-quartz-gtk flag: `cabal install gtk -f have-quartz-gtk` (of course with the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH set as suggested by ErikR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `pkg-config` cannot find the file `gtk+-2.0.pc`:

> requires pkg-config package gtk+-2.0-any,
>   not found in the pkg-config database

Steps to troublshoot:

1. Check which directories `pkg-config` is configured to look for `.pc` files with:

   ```
   $  pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
   ```
2. On my system, `gtk+-2.0.pc` resides in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. I extended the search path by setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable:

   ```
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:
   ```
3. Test that `pkg-config` can find gtk+-2.0:

   ```
   pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --exists && echo Found the library
   ```

   No output means the .pc file was not found. Another command you can use
   for checking is:

   ```
   pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs --print-errors
   ```

   You'll either see an error message or a long list of flags for the C compiler which tells it how to link with the gtk libraries.
4. Another tip for finding the .pc file is to use the `locate` command (assuming the locate database has been updated):

   ```
   locate '*.pc' | grep gtk
   ```

Comment: thank you for your fast solution, but it does not work for me. I changed the variable of PKG_CONFIG_PATH and got the answer "Found the library" in the next step. After another failed try in installing, I checked the error message (2nd part of 3) and it gave me a lot of flags like "-L/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.29/lib". How can I link these flags?

Comment: Just saying "it does not work" is not very helpful. Please update your question with what you tried and what the error message is.

Comment: As per @eugenk's comment above: `cabal install gtk -f have-quartz-gtk` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Homebrew, you can install gtk+3 by typing:

```
brew install gtk+3
```